# How to make a border inside of a table?

Tags: html

I am brand new to html and was wondering how I could make a border inside of a table? What I am trying to make is exactly this:

[image]

Of course I have made some code to show you that I am trying to make my table look like that, however all I have been able to do is this:

[image]

The code for what I have shown in the second picture is here:

```
<table border="4">
     <caption>Table - 6 -</caption>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Item 1</th>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 5</td>
            <td>Item 6</td>
            <td>Item 7</td>
        </tr>

</table>
```

I am trying to **use no CSS in the webpage**. I would love to understand more of HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without CSS, the only HTML elements which have native borders are `table` and `img`. I'd go with a nested table here:

```html
<table border="4">
     <caption>Table - 6 -</caption>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2"><table border="4"><tr><td>Item 1</td></tr></table></th>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 5</td>
            <td>Item 6</td>
            <td>Item 7</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

You'd never want to do this in an actual website though, as HTML should not be used for presentation, only CSS.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. I tried to do add a border inside of the table but it wasn't coming out right since I didn't do it as shown. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

You can put "Item 1" inside a `<span>` element and style the span:

```
<table border="4">
     <caption>Table - 6 -</caption>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2"><span style="border:2px solid black;">Item 1</span></th>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 5</td>
            <td>Item 6</td>
            <td>Item 7</td>
        </tr>

</table>
```

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tfs4f8sd/

Note that I have used inline CSS. Just give the elements you want an inner border a class name and style it in CSS.